# Extract the number before a file extension (.ps1) in a string

Tags: regex, powershell

A cmdlet that creates a file returns a block of text, and in that is the name of the file. The file has a format of string[number].ps1, but the number is random, so I would like to extract that number and store it in a variable.

Block of text for reference:

```
  +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
    \ a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script35.ps1:20 char:8\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
    +              ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script35.ps1:20 char:3\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
    +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
    \ a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script35.ps1:21 char:8\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;\n\
    +              ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script35.ps1:21 char:3\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;\n\
    +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
```

I thought `$result -match '\d\d+(?=\.\w+)'` would work, but it only returned the lines the number was found on, instead of just the number.

Answer (score 1):

With a *collection* (as opposed to a single value) as the LHS, the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match):

- acts as a *filter* - i.e. returns the subarray of *matching elements* rather than a Boolean
- does *not* populate the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) with the matching operator's results.

That's why your output comprised the matching lines *as a whole*.

---

To return only the matching parts, you can use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) with the `-Regex` option to loop over your array of lines, in which case `$Matches` *is* populated for each input line:

```bsh
# Array of sample lines.
# For illustrative purposes I've tweaked the `script<number>.ps1`
# tokens to have successive numbers.
$lines = @'
 +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
    \ a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script35.ps1:20 char:8\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
    +              ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script36.ps1:20 char:3\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
    +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
    \ a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script37.ps1:21 char:8\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;\n\
    +              ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script38.ps1:21 char:3\n+         using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;\n\
    +         ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Perform the matching, line by line,
# and output each line's matching part,
# resulting in an array of strings.
# Prepend 
#     $result = 
# to store the array in a variable.
switch -Regex ($lines) {
  '\d+(?=\.\w+)' { $Matches[0] } # to extract only the *1st* match,
                                   # append `; break` inside the { ... }
}
```

The above yields:

```
35
36
37
38
```

Note that `switch` also supports reading lines directly from a file, using the `-File` option
(`switch -Regex -File $filePath { ... }`).